# Скрыть файлы из публичного доступа в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Задача состоит в том, чтобы скрыть документы пользователя из публичного доступа, их может просматривать только пользователь какой загрузил эти файлы. Не знаю какой вариант лучше и есть ли смысл выносить файлы из папки web. Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Доброе утро. Используйте rbac

Comment: @slo_nik гляну, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант А. Менее гибкий**

- Выносим файлы, закрытые от просмотра, в отдельную папку внутри web,
  например `protected_uploads`.
- Устанавливаем куки для конкретного пользователя на просмотр файла.    Например: файл называется `my_file_325835628.png`, для нужного нам
  пользователя ставим куки `my_file_325835628=true`, если добавляются
  еще файлы, добавляем новый куки, если удаляем разрешение, то ставим
  false или просто удаляем куки  В htaccess для папки
- `protected_uploads` прописываем правила типа таких (на корректность    правил не претендую):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.png [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !$1=true [NC]
> RewriteRule \.(png)$ - [NC,F,L]
> ```

**Вариант Б. Более гибкий**

- Выносим нужные файлы за пределы папки `web`
- Где-то у храним данные, какие файлы доступны пользователю (база, сессия, куки)
- Создаем контроллер для отображения нужных файлов (или не создаем, а используем существующие) и модель для работы с таблицей в базе, где хранится эта информация, например `FilesAccess`
- В контроллере ставим экшн для отображения файлов:

  // на корректность кода так же не претендую, наверняка в Yii предусмотрены более продуманные варианты отображения изображений, нужно читать документацию

  ```
      public function actionShowFile() {
          $fileName = Yii::$app->request->get("file_name");
          $allowed = FilesAccess::isAllowed($fileName); // Этот метод проверяет в табилце `files_access` доступен ли файл для доступа данному пользователю
          if ( $allowed ) {
              $response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
              $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
              $response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
              $response->stream = fopen("серверный/путь/до/нужной/папки" . $fileName, 'r');
              return $response->send();
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: Отлично, все работает как нужно. Спасибо. Только теперь не могу разобраться как варианте Б забрать из папки больше одного файла. Не подскажете?

Comment: Да уж, все оказалось гораздо проще. Достаточно было у каждого изображения в сорсе прописать путь к нужному экшену.

Comment: Еще это можно упростить до одной строчки `Yii::$app->getResponse()->sendFile($path_to_file)`